# Ubuntu not using RVM ruby version

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm

I"m using Ubuntu and RVM. I've run the command

```
rvm use 2.1.2
```

Running

```
ruby -v
```

gives me the 2.1.2 version.

When I start rails I get the following error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2
```

But RVM doesn't even have 2.3.1 installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may have `apt install`ed ruby. For example, when I run `apt show ruby`, on my system, I get this

```
$ apt show ruby  
Package: ruby
Version: 1:2.3.0+1
Priority: optional
Section: interpreters
Source: ruby-defaults
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
...
```

Clearly, the ruby version is **2.3.x** here. So I suggest you `apt remove ruby` first. If that doesn't solve the problem, it is possible that there is a problem with your `$PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`ruby -v` gives you the ruby version installed on your system, not the current ruby version used by RVM.

To see which ruby version is currently used by RVM, use `rvm list`. Make sure it's using ruby version 2.1.2 by running `rvm use ruby-2.1.2`

From your question, it seems Rails is using your system ruby instead of RVM ruby.